# Recover account from 64-byte string

Tags: addresses, private-key, string, recovery

In October 2015, I generated an account and backed up two things: the address, and a mysterious 64-byte string. I can see the correct balance on the address, so no problem here. I initially assumed that the 64-byte string was my private key, but I now understand that private keys are only 32 bytes.

Did I back up my public key instead of my private key? It does not seem so, the generated address does not match my address:

```
from eth_keys import KeyAPI
key = "xxx" # the actual 64-byte string
pub = KeyAPI.PublicKey(key.encode())
print(pub.to_address())
```

Is this the seed for a HD Wallet? Again, none of the first 100 addresses matches my address:

```
from hdwallet import BIP44HDWallet
from hdwallet.cryptocurrencies import EthereumMainnet
from hdwallet.derivations import BIP44Derivation
from hdwallet.utils import generate_mnemonic
from typing import Optional

KEY = "xxx"

bip44_hdwallet: BIP44HDWallet = BIP44HDWallet(cryptocurrency=EthereumMainnet)
bip44_hdwallet.from_seed(seed=KEY.encode().hex())
bip44_hdwallet.clean_derivation()
print("Base HD Path:  m/44'/60'/0'/0/{address_index}", "\n")

for address_index in range(100):
    bip44_derivation: BIP44Derivation = BIP44Derivation(
        cryptocurrency=EthereumMainnet, account=0, change=False, address=address_index
    )
    bip44_hdwallet.from_path(path=bip44_derivation)
    print(f"({address_index}) {bip44_hdwallet.path()} {bip44_hdwallet.address()} 0x{bip44_hdwallet.private_key()}")
    bip44_hdwallet.clean_derivation()
```

Am I missing something? Can it be another path? I do not remember the wallet software I used back then to generate the account.

I also tried to enter the hex representation (128 characters) as the private key in MyCrypto. I got the following message:

> Your wallet is encrypted. Please enter the password.

I do not remember setting up a password, and if I did, I would probably have saved it along the key in my password manager. MyCrypto does not accept empty passwords.

I am running out of ideas. Any hint?

Comment: Does the 64 bytes look like hexadecimal or completely random bytes? If you are curious the address result from the truncation of `keccak(publicKey)` to 20 bytes.

Comment: It is not an hexadecimal string. If I convert to hexadecimal, I get 128 characters. In my first code example, `pub.to_address()` does [truncate the keccak to 20 bytes](https://github.com/ethereum/eth-keys/blob/dd4f00a5d2f2b394665ccecc9817f753e58cc7bc/eth_keys/utils/address.py#L6), so at least I know this is not my public key.